# Show children of a Taxonomy Term

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, routes

I make use of the view: "taxonomy term". Is there an easy way to also show the children of a term, next to the nodes beloging to this term?

Example:

```
Cars
- Volvo
--- Family_cars
--- Sports_cars
- Honda
--- Parts
--- ...
Trucks
- ...
```

When you see the "cars" page I want to show all articles about cars (but not about Volvo, Honda, ...) AND I want to show the children (Volvo, Honda, ...) When you click one of these I want to show all the articles belonging with them, again with their children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to display nodes that have a term, but not the nodes that have a child term.

You also want to display the child terms.

There are some different ways of handling this, since you are using the default view, you should get a View already that displays the correct nodes - so all you are missing is the terms.

The best way to deal with this, is not through Views, but a module called [Taxonomy menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu). It will create a menu with the same structure of a vocabulary which can expend, to show child menus. As with menus you get use the block system to add them on the term pages. Beware of a bug with the menu system though see [the issue](http://drupal.org/node/942782).

A quick fix is to add this in your settings file:

```
$conf['menu_default_active_menus'] = array(
  'navigation',
  'management',
  'user-menu',
  'main-menu',
  'your-menu-here',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

1.taxonomy/term/x -- where x is the term id to show, a number.

2.to show children nodes you need to add a depth variable. The syntax is:
taxonomy/term/x/y -- where x is the term id to show, and y is the depth to go below x.

3.to show all children nodes. The syntax is:
taxonomy/term/x/all -- where x is the term id to show.